# pymel.core.workspace.getcwd() doesn't return project directory as intended

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I try to make simple tools  in maya. I use this script to get the current project directory:

> pymel.core.workspace.getcwd()

Sometimes this script is going well. But sometimes the results were not appropriate, like this : **D:\MyProject\Movie\EP01\SQ010\SH001**

My maya file is in : **D:\MyProject\Movie\EP01\SQ010\SH001\scenes**

Well, sometimes missing one folder (it's weird)

After searching in google, i get this link : https://github.com/LumaPictures/pymel/issues/32

They say, i should use

> getPath()

than

> getcwd()

I have tried but, this script still not work because the result is : **C:\Users\aditya\Documents\maya\projects\default**

Any suggestions? Or what did i miss?
I'm using maya 2016 by the way..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PyMel I would recommand to use the conventional Maya command, from [Maya's documentation](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/internalVar.html) using the command **internalVar** with the flag **userWorkspaceDir** should return your current project directory. As follow ;

```
project_dir = cmds.internalVar(userWorkspaceDir=True)
print project
```

Comment: Hi Mehdi, thank you for your respon. Finally, i use this script to get my own workspace directory --> **pymel.core.sceneName().dirname()**. So far, i have no problem. For now :)